# Conditional validation with Vuelidate?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have a form, where different validations can apply, depending on the parameter `action`, stored in  VUEX store. I try this:

```
data: function() {
   const validations = {
      sendToProject: {
        cardProject: {
          required,
        },
      },
      recallToBranch: {
        fioReceiver: {
          required,
        }
      }
   }
   return {
     validations,
   }
},
validations() {
  return {
    q: this.validations[this.action]  // supposed to be this.validations['sendToProject']
  }
},
computed: {
  ...mapGetters({
    action: 'action',
  }),
},
```

This actually works, but throws an error while bootstraping:

`[Vue warn]: Error in render function: "TypeError: can't convert undefined to object"`

and that error prevents non-Vue code (Bootstrap jQuery plugins initializations, etc) from execution.

How to fix? Thanks.

Comment: I hate to say this, but Vuelidate is really a bad library. I had the same issues so I changed to https://github.com/baianat/vee-validate and it's much better

Answer (score 17):

Have you tried to use requiredIf in required validator. For example:

```
validations: {
  anyProp: {
    required: requiredIf(function (abc) {
      return abc > 10 && abc < 20
    })
  }
}
```