# How to add condition based url validation in vuelidate

Tags: vue.js, vuelidate

I used `vuelidate` in my vue.js project form validation. It's works good.

But I need URL validation with a condition based. My requirement below.

My create meeting form have location type field & that based location info field.

Screenshots below:

Type - 1

[image]

Type - 2

[image]

If the user chooses virtual URL validate added. otherwise not to add URL validate.

If anyone has this solution Kindly share me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conditional validation with Vuelidate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47630910/conditional-validation-with-vuelidate)

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I already used `requiredIf`. But I want URL validation with the condition based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got my solution. It's based on `validation` callback return object.

```
validations() {
  const self = this;
  return {
    model: {
      location: { required },
      location_info: {
        required,
        condUrlVald: self.model.location == 'V' ? url : required
      }
    }
  }
},
```

`model.location` is location type field variable. Value 'V' is location type 'Virtual'

Refer by: https://github.com/vuelidate/vuelidate/issues/770#issuecomment-745101885